# Getting randomly 502 error using NGINX

Tags: nginx

This is one of the content of access.log file:

```
 {"time":"2016-01-13T06:40:40+00:00", "remote_addr":"109.100.96.13", 
"remote_user":"-", "host":"myhost", "request":"GET /mypath/myurl/ HTTP/1.1",
 "status":"502", "body_bytes_sent":"568", 
"referer":"https://search.yahoo.com/", "user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 
6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 
Safari/537.36", "request_time":"120.231", "handler":"hhvm", "country":"RO",
 "android_dupe_bug":"", "ssl_cipher":"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256", 
"ssl_protocol":"TLSv1.2"}
```

and this is the error.log

```
2016/01/13 07:09:35 [error] 9134#0: *677679 limiting requests, excess: 0.729
 by zone "bots", client: 5.189.177.31, server: , request: "GET /cgi-bin
/index.cgi HTTP/1.1", host: "54.93.166.80"
```

My quest that I am visited by to many bots, but I am not 100%. Using this command:

```
pnl --yesterday--php --bots --fields ua | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

The result is that i was visited by more then 40.000 bots (google, apple, yahoo,....). 
How do i solve this problem ? thx

UPDATE

this is the nginx.conf file:

```
## Ansible managed: /srv/hypernode/ansible-playbooks/roles/magweb/templates/nginx/nginx.conf modified on 2015-12-10 11:51:53 by jenkins on hn-control3

user app;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    # default: 1m, so required to allow photo uploads
    # see ticket #1315276 --WdG
    client_max_body_size 120m;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # GeoIP support is included in the 12.04 nginx
    # This enables logging, and the following:
    #    if ($geoip_country_code ~ (BR|CN|KR|RU) ) {
    #      return 403;
    #    }

    geoip_country         /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;

    log_format hypernode '{'
                           '"time":"$time_iso8601", '
                           '"remote_addr":"$remote_addr", '
                           '"remote_user":"$remote_user", '
                           '"host":"$http_host", '
                           '"request":"$request", '
                           '"status":"$status", '
                           '"body_bytes_sent":"$body_bytes_sent", '
                           '"referer":"$http_referer", '
                           '"user_agent":"$http_user_agent", '
                           '"request_time":"$request_time", '
                           '"handler":"$log_handler", '
                           '"country":"$geoip_country_code", '
                           '"android_dupe_bug":"$android_log_dupe", '
                           '"ssl_cipher":"$ssl_cipher", '
                           '"ssl_protocol":"$ssl_protocol"'
                         '}';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log hypernode;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types       text/html text/xml text/plain text/css text/js application/xml application/x-javascript application/json;

    # website has been administratively disabled for security reasons

    # CDN compatibility, so that the proxied IP turns up in ACL and logs
    include /etc/nginx/cdn.conf;

    # Rate limit all non-google/bing bots
    # https://gist.github.com/supairish/2951524
    # (Alternatively, use key $binary_remote_addr to rate limit per ip.)
    # This config shares the same rate for all bots.
    # These regexes are case-insensitive. --WdG
    map $http_user_agent $limit_bots {
        default '';
        ~*(google|bing|pingdom|monitis.com|Zend_Http_Client) '';
        ~*(http|crawler|spider|bot|search|ForusP|Wget/|Python-urllib|PHPCrawl|bGenius) 'bot';
    }

    # An empty '$limit_bots' would disable rate limiting for this requests
    limit_req_zone $limit_bots zone=bots:1m rate=1r/s;
    limit_req_log_level error;

    index index.html index.php;

    include /etc/nginx/app/http.*;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/ssl/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: It's strange that your `nginx` would be responding to using HTTP **502**, rather than HTTP 503, as the latter is the default per the `nginx` [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req_status).  Could you show us the `limit_req_zone` and related lines from your `nginx` config?

Comment: @TJSaunders see my update please and Thx

Comment: Thanks for the config.  I'm wondering if the `error` log entry about rate limiting is _unrelated_ to the 502; from searching around on `nginx` and 502s, it seems they happen when `nginx` can't connect/proxy to a backend server.  Are there any entries in the `error.log` around that `"time":"2016-01-13T06:40:40+00:00"` timeframe (from the 502 `access.log` entry) that might indicate an issue along these lines?

Comment: In the access log there is a lot of them , most of it has the status code, 200, which is Ok. As you can the errors is related to bots. I am visited by more 70.000 bots/ day (adwords). My datatraffic is limited to 250GB  and 5000 visitors/ days. I am wondering if is it a problem ?